# How to have third-party regex module search return instances of zero occurrences as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want my output to be counts of matches as well as a "0" output for terms where there was no match. Is there an easy way to incorporate this into an existing regex search (ideally compatible with the third-party regex module: https://pypi.org/project/regex/)?

print(Counter(reg.findall('[ABCD][ABCD]', "AAABC", overlapped=True)))

For example: Here I would want AD, BA, BB, BD, DA, DB, DC, DD to be included as '0' in the output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the module you mentioned, but I doubt this could be done. Imagine your functionality for regex like `[ABCD]+`: there is infinitely many possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need any pair of two letters A..D or mentioned pairs?

In the first case you can use regex `'[A-D]{2}'` (result: counted 2: `['AA', 'AB']`)

in the second: `'AD|BA|BB|BD|DA|DB|DC|DD'` (result: counted 0: `[]`)

Look at [tests](https://pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u52092_sB3mw8W7v0h7KB5mbhZSTpEm_v0.py).